# JAVA::NOT ABLE TO CALL JAVA METHOD FROM SETONCHANGE()

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I used java and jsf.
I created dynamic datatable in java file.
can i call java method from setOnchange() event?

I am able to call java script function from setOnchange() event.
see the below code which is working fine for java script.

```
HtmlSelectOneMenu selectOneMenu = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
selectOneMenu.setStyleClass("dropdownStyleTwo");
selectOneMenu.setOnchange("openWin(this);IGNORE_UNLOAD=false");
```

i wrote openwin() function in java script.

but i am not able to call java method change().
code which is not working.

```
HtmlSelectOneMenu selectOneMenu = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
selectOneMenu.setStyleClass("dropdownStyleTwo");
selectOneMenu.setOnchange("myclass.change();IGNORE_UNLOAD=false");
```

myclass is the bean of class Test.
If user select any value from dropdown i want to call change java method.
This function will apply the same selected dropdown value to the other record also.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, `onchange` refers to the JavaScript event, so when you want to register Java code, you should add a value change listener and call Java code there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but i am getting this error The method setValueChangeListener(MethodBinding) in the type UIInput is not applicable for the arguments (String).selectMenu.setValueChangeListener("myclass.change");

Answer (score 0):

Rendered HTML is rendered on the client, and need additional means to communicate with server.
Usually you have some JSF framework, that links your server code with client HTML, by using JS and REST calls underneath. So you can always call JS in your client, but for server call you need some interpretation from client side.

Take a look at JSF frameworks, like Primefaces, that can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if method name and caller is: setOnchange or setOnChange (C capital)